# Add a foreign keyboard layout to Gnome in Debian 8

Tags: debian, gnome, keyboard-layout, locale

I would like to add an Italian keyboard layout as an input source, but my system only lists English layouts.  I suppose that this is because I didn't select any locale other than English during installation.  What can I do know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to install keyboard-configuration package
`sudo apt-get install keyboard-configuration`
And then follow this [guide](https://wiki.debian.org/Keyboard)

> edit /etc/default/keyboard manually, here's an example:

```
# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE

# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.

XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="us,de,fr,ua,ru"
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBOPTIONS="grp:alt_shift_toggle"

BACKSPACE="guess"
```

> XKBMODEL is a keyboard model variable (look at a /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/base.lst (plain text) or /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/base.xml (XML) for a full list);
>
> XKBLAYOUT variable contains a list of used layouts;
>
> "grp:alt_shift_toggle" sets a layout switching key combination (+).

Answer (score 7):

Press Super-key (corespondent to Windows-key), search (at the top) `Region & Language`, and confirm with Enter. Then press `+` and add the desired language flavor.[image]