# Changing keyboard settings for Spanish

Tags: debian, gnome, keyboard-layout

I'm using Debian 8.2 Jessie. I'm in argentina, and my system is not configured for my keyboard with Spanish layout. What packages do I need and what to do with them?

If I go Gnome's settings > keyboard > input sources the only language is english.

I absolutely don't want to change the language of my system, I want everything possible in english, with the exception of the input source.

I have aptitude installed.

Edit 1: I followed the [guide](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/211598/add-a-foreign-keyboard-layout-to-gnome-in-debian-8) provided by the comments. Still doesn't work, but two important progress: this is what it looks like now /etc/default/keyboard, note "es" (espaniol = spanish) as default language.

```
# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE

# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.

XKBMODEL="geniuskb19e"
XKBLAYOUT="es"
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBOPTIONS="compose:rctrl,terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp"

BACKSPACE="guess"
```

Also the other configurations are exactly what I specified when I did `dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`.

The problem with that was that my keyboard model was not available. It's a genius, model K639, product name: kb 06-XE. I don't know if it's equivalent to other models, but neither of these 2 names were in the possible models list for that command.

Other good news is that now if I restart the computer, before logging in I can see a little button in the top right corner, and it has "en" and "es" as languages. That wasn't there before. But after logging in it dissapears.

Edit 2: I could solve completely the problem. After doing the suggested solution, the only thing left was going to settings > keyboard > input source > '+' > '...' > 'other' > scrolling down and adding spanish. Then a new menu exactly like the described in the edit before appeared in the top bar at right with language selection.
Unfortunately I don't know if it was a necessary step to to whatś described in Edit 1, but doing it suffices. Other people should just try what's on edit 2.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/keyboard-layouts.html.en

Comment: @michas That says how to do it *once* you got the language installed. It is trivial to reach that screen for me but simply there is only one language displayed to choose and it's english.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/211598/add-a-foreign-keyboard-layout-to-gnome-in-debian-8

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I followed those steps and got some progress! But still not there.

Comment: Cannot help much you more, I only use a Portuguese keyboard in OS/X all the Linuxes in my server farm are headless.

Comment: Or rather, I do have a Debian working with a Portuguese keyboard, however wife has it at work. If you do not solve it by tomorrow, I can ask her to bring it along.

Comment: @Rui F Riberio if it would not produce problems or incovenieces, you could! That would be very very kind.

Comment: I managed to have a look, did not manage to get to the crux of it.  I *could* swear last year I forced the creation of a xorg.conf file in another netbook (as nowadays it does not exist by default), and forced there the pt keyboard. So I am afraid I do not have much more to add.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Well thanks!!! I hope you have a great day!